# smooth scrolling using css

Tags: html, css, scroll, smoothing

I'm pretty new to coding and I have a single page site (html and css) with anchor points for various sections through the page. These are linked in the nav and instead of jumping down the page, I was wondering if it was possible to allow the page to scroll smoothly - without having to use a javascript.

The only thing I have found like it is http://jsfiddle.net/YYPKM/3/

/*
      *Scrolling
    */

```
a[ id= "servicios" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
-webkit-transform: translateY( 0px);
transform: translateY( 0px );}

a[ id= "galeria" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
-webkit-transform: translateY( -500px );
transform: translateY( -500px );}

a[ id= "contacto" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
-webkit-transform: translateY( -1000px );
transform: translateY( -1000px );}
```

and I can not seem to get it to work. If anyone had any tips, that would be amazing.

Comment: Can you post your code that isn't working?

Comment: The code you've posted is the code from the fiddle. That code is specific to that app. You wouldn't be able to use that same code for your project. Do you understand that?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it easy by looking this demo once...

[SMOOTH SCROLLING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/U7zE3/light/)

This is for your reference,Try to code in jquery like this..

```
$(function() {

   $('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden');

   function updateSize() {
      var winWidth  = $(window).width(),
          winHeight = $(window).height(),
          wrapSum   = $('.box').siblings().length;
       $('#wrap').css({
           width:winWidth*(wrapSum/2),
           height:winHeight*(wrapSum/3)
       });
       $('.box').css({
           width:winWidth,
           height:winHeight
       });  
   } updateSize(); 

    $(window).resize(function() {
        updateSize();
    });

    $('ul#nav a').click(function () {
        $('a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $('html, body').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 1000);    
        return false;
    });

});
```